# Capturing "run-lengths" in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have some data in a DataFrame with the following structure *(this is mock data)*

```
In[67]: dts
Out[67]: 
                       timestamp        lag up_down
0     2016-09-05 00:00:00.000000  10.975553    True
1     2016-09-05 00:18:52.229551   4.757383   False
2     2016-09-05 00:36:39.365184   8.555124   False
3     2016-09-05 00:49:42.976653   9.564206   False
4     2016-09-05 01:04:53.626044   2.380522   False
5     2016-09-05 01:19:50.601259  11.283831    True
6     2016-09-05 01:38:13.121235  10.648995    True
                         ...        ...     ...
12902 2017-01-17 12:26:18.614783   0.226865    True
12903 2017-01-17 12:36:56.317562   0.485407   False
12904 2017-01-17 12:47:07.889736   8.901771    True
12905 2017-01-17 13:05:15.205444  10.114116    True
12906 2017-01-17 13:23:50.930639   7.975374   False
```

I have a criteria which makes a particular timestamp "inoperable" - either the lag is greater than 7 or the `up_down` is `False`. That is, a boolean mask on my data with this criteria would be

```
dts[(dts['lag'] >= 7) | (dts['up_down'] == False)]
```

#### My question

I am interested in "average run-lengths" with this criteria, though. I want to calculate the average length of time (derived from the timestamps) for which this criteria holds true for consecutive timestamps. **What is a straightforward way to capture runs based on a criteria like this**?

---

#### My thoughts and approach thus far

In practice I have all of the steps I need to solve this problem

1. I can rudimentarily determine whether a criteria is met in consecutive timestamps by using the `index` on the boolean mask mentioned above and checking whether it was incremented by 1.
2. I can then loop over each collection of consecutive indices, and subtract the first timestamp from the last timestamp to generate a timedelta.
3. I can then average the timedeltas

This has been my solution so far, but my real issue here is with step 2 - I know it is very much frowned upon in pandas to loop over a DataFrame by row, and I feel like there should be some grouping mechanism which I can use here to directly map my `last_timestamp - first_timestamp` formulation to and average over.

#### Generating mock data

If you want to play with some mock data of the same form, this may be handy

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd

start_date = datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 5)
end_date = datetime.datetime.now()

dts = []
cur_date = start_date 
while cur_date < end_date:
    dts.append((cur_date, np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=12.0), 
                bool(random.getrandbits(1))))
    cur_date += datetime.timedelta(minutes=np.random.uniform(10, 20))
dts = pd.DataFrame(dts, columns=['timestamp', 'lag', 'up_down'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
dts['criteria'] = (dts['lag'] >= 7) | (dts['up_down'] == False)
change = (h.criteria!=h.criteria.shift())
dts['ts'] = dts[change]['timestamp']

(df.ts.bfill()-df.ts.ffill()).shift(-1).fillna(0)
```

Bring the timestamps in a new column `ts` only for the row when you encounter a criteria change.

Backfilling and forward filling that column brings the min and max per group on the same row. Then you simply do the difference, shift the result to realign on the appropriate row, and fill non relevant values 0 duration.

Comment: Hey @Boud, thank you for this. One concern - doesn't this introduce a bug if the first value run does not match the criteria? Say, the first 100 values all have a `criteria` value of false. Then with your shifting, the `change` is true for the very first position, right?

Comment: Could be, didn't take the time to look at the borderline cases as it is not the real problem you have here and it is easy homework for you to deal with the edge case (adding a fake line, turning the boolean vector row 0 into false, etc. nothing complex). But you should certainly look at it

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I ended up doing, thanks for your help! Not sure why this was downvoted.